# Data Binding for generic classes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I have a layout that applies to a generic base class for an activity. The activity is defined like this:

```
public abstract class MyActivity<TUserType extends UserType> extends AppCompatActivity
```

I would like to be able to use data binding for this class, but when I try to use a setting from this class in the layout xml, the setting is not recognized when I compile. This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:res="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="activity"
            type="com.exampl.MyActivity"/>
    </data>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:visibility="@{activity.progressBarVisibility}"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

"progressBarVisibility" is defined in MyActivity, and is public. I'm guessing I probably have to define the UserType, but I don't know how to do that xml-side. Or is this not supported yet?

Answer (score 0):

No need to define UserType.
This is my case:

public abstract class BaseStateVM extends BasePVM {

```
@Bindable
public int getState() {
    return state;
}
```

```
<data>

    <import type="com.rayman.v2ex.widget.anotations.PageState" />

    <import type="com.rayman.v2ex.viewmodel.BaseStateVM" />

    <import type="android.view.View" />

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="BaseStateVM" />
</data>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/loading_view"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="@{viewModel.state==PageState.LOADING?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE,default=visible}">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will help you.
And The complete code is [here](https://github.com/LenaYan/V2EXAndroidClient/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/state_loading_layout.xml).